# How do you deploy a smart contract from a Gnosis Safe?

Tags: ethers.js, gnosis-safe, gnosis, safe-core-sdk

I want to deploy a smart contract using my Safe. I know how to do it with Ethers.js using an EOA, but how can I have my own Gnosis Safe execute the contract deployment?